# Yii2 папка для vendor

Tags: php, yii2, структуры

Есть расширение в папке вендор и есть задача его расширить. Так вот, куда лучше складывать эти самые классы, думал в папку components, но как-то не логично получается.

P.S: я понимаю что можно куда угодно, но все же хотелось бы придерживаться структуры самого фреймворка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я свои расширения храню в папке extensions. Думаю это логично. В vendor чужие расширения, которые я использую как есть. А в папке extensions мои расширения, которые я сам написал, оттуда же деплою на гитхаб, если нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне и было нужно.